# Decoding a base 64 string to a file

Tags: python, file, decoding

I am writing a program that receives a base 64 string from a device. That string is an encoded json file, and I would like to interpret it as such.

if I do this (using the python base64 lib):

```
decoded = base64.decodestring(base64str) 
print(decoded)
```

Then it prints a bunch of gibberish, since the original data was not a string, but a file.

I can see the name of the file between the gibberish, so I guess I received the data correctly, but need to interpret it directly as a file instead of a string.

I have looked around a lot and have not managed to make it work. Trying to save the string to a file obviously just saves all of the gibberish to a file

I would appreciate your help in how to do this!

The base 64 string:

```
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
```

The "decoded" string:

```
!A ux o3d3xx.jsonUT   �Ymo�8������P ��'��6RyY�{�ݮ�I m��LӮ��-�̨hp�f� X�[�/uK�G���#A;d����p΅l[r����L��3�3�:���6�s��/�������J�ڠg�/?k� ���7h2�ճ6< ��\���|�`d�9�!�������:v�?siB��/�/�
                                  /��_�����K,�`r�d4����{ J�                                                      � `��#��{4J�    h#�p�$��s ��ԇY��\����o�J�:��6�<wH�xR��{,����           ��,�u��,�?J7W|@� i�哉K�$9����(�W��qZ���-��cu��6s!��P���Y�6G����R�v�-;́B��ĭ�Vܯ7��,��y�,�ψ@1�zH~ ��8~.��'Q��}����6��H���ZV(j7�`����漏t�(������:�S�^��o^t��fl?I��9N�,�G���A�ŷ ��a���\�����Nr���p�]ڍ��� ��R�,��m@��S�D��9����uZ�4�,�r(,�E�֫hCv@C�FIX�:                         ���Z�0�                                                                �z�fI /%��5�                                       �U��o�s�'R�p�yT��h.h8�.&�x��Q/��_���
      �q�_�-�                                                                   -���`F���)F]� ���� ��tXU�*�`M�2�rBd2�DFx��������3�A�h4jf�aKΩ�l3�:�d���+��!�4��z�6�Y8�N����u��$#^���0:q��#LHay�F��%-�I�j^%M��THFc��uW}�;n}nuGc�S�k��O���Y���[��V3�@)5O*��/�9h՛O�vo0
                  ⠞�ߴ�Q�a�~��|R�a�^�<�Ƈ6��+ō�ڠ''�1s�+5��+��     ���                �݀�7p���(����Q�H?<�DA��Q�]EV�I'P����T�>��`j� c       4�A��W>%�ؕ�ޭ7�,7[�                                                     &���u?�LRz�~�q8<�����ԉ.�}� �.Q�Y\H�Tѿ+�K�R �0#��fZ�fv���#W�9��ZM`�KV<���?u�M��iʅGԫ#�!�@��X�1z�|"V1�               ��ivP���. !�C.�!�                                                     g#d��9$UhR�z�Z`� �O�X�����a�ld��}�"�
                 ({UxC��+��+�-构�=> ����g*�8xK���\�xY�3q4$/�ɅZaO�y��R�/2���>�\
=��g��h>0D���P���i�p�@�F���: f�R��'@V�K=a�����M�z[�A�n���b�f���>Oj�A�4��i��r�(D�Gim&�q�(Vi\o]�J���Lש7�xE���t��k�V��J���O�À���L,�&����uJ�qk��MQ/Vn���;��Ye��nF� ��!!��f����_��
                                                                                                                                                      �?7������P�_ A!�_ A ��o3d3xx.jsonUTuxPKFy
```

Hopefully there is a way to extract and save the file without having to transform the string at all.

Comment: According to your understanding, what is the difference between a file and a string?

Comment: I would think a file would probably have some additional encoding regarding its name and size. This app https://www.base64decode.org/ is able to produce a file (name and all) from the base 64 string. but I need to do it from python code

Comment: Of these three entities:  1) a string containing the file name, 2) a string containing the contents of the file, 3) a string containing metadata about the file, such as the file size, last modified date, etc. along with the filename, which string is being produced by your device?

Comment: I added both strings to the question

Comment: *This app base64decode.org is able to produce a file (name and all) from the base 64 string* --- That app does not produce "a file".  It takes a string or a filename (from which it extracts the contents of the file as a string), and produces another string.

Comment: *Hopefully there is a way to extract and save the file* -- There is no "file".  There is the whole string, and there are portions of the string, which apparently you are interested in.  A portion of the string could be a file's name, which is a string, too.

Comment: @7stud Did you actually try that app? When I tried it with that string, the app didn't show me a string but offered me a file download. Of a zip file. Because the base64-decoded data is the contents of a zip file.

Comment: Yes, I did try it, but I was not offered a file download--maybe if strings are over a certain size the app doesn't display the decoded string and it offers you a file download instead?  In any case, any file produced by that app has nothing to do with base64 encoding/decoding, which takes a string and produces another string.   The way the app packages the result is irrelevant

Comment: @7stud Offer a file download because of *the size*? You don't think it would make more sense to offer a file download because it recognizes the data as the contents of a zip file?

Comment: @7stud Just to close the loop, I just checked: The offered zip file is 2005 bytes large, and it's exactly the same 2005 bytes that are also in the OP's `decoded`. So no real "packaging" going on there. It apparently really just recognizes the zip data as such and is like *"no point displaying this, save it as a file"*.

Comment: @StefanPochmann,  After your hint about the zipfile, I came up with the same solution you did--it took me awhile to figure out an encoding error I was getting when using io.StringIO, but then I realized I could just use io.BytesIO.

Comment: I thought I would just explain to the op a little: it's strings all the way down.  You ***always*** have to know how your strings are encoded in order to decode them.  There are no "files", there are just strings.  Sure, strings can be stored in files.  In your situation, your string was zip encoded then base64 encoded.  You failed to mention the zip encoding.  Once Stefan Pochman figured that out, it was just a matter of decoding using base64 to get the zip encoded string, then zip decoding to get your json.

Comment: @StefanPochmann,  *So no real "packaging" going on there.* -- I don't want to get too technical here, but the converter takes a string and produces a string.  The fact that the convert does not display the op's string to you and instead writes the string to a file called `xxxx.yyy` and offers the file to you for downloading is the "packaging" I was referring to.

Comment: @7stud I didn't know it was a zip file :) I thought it was json and that's what created all the confusion. I did not create the program that sends the data and the device's manual did not mention the format. This is all I had to work with:
"Output parameters: Configuration as a data BLOB: binary/base64". Luckily Stefan figured it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @cmperezg, No worries.  Luckily, there are smart guys like Stefan Pochmann around.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I do `print(decoded[:20])` I'm actually shown this:

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

That `PK\x03\x04` is a "magic number" for a [zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)). So treat it as such. Either save it to a file named like "mydata.zip" and then extract it like you would extract any zip file, or process it in Python for example like this:

```
...
decoded = base64.decodestring(base64str) 

import io, zipfile, json, pprint

with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(decoded)) as zf:
    for name in zf.namelist():
        print(name)
        with zf.open(name) as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read().decode())

pprint.pprint(data)
```

With your data, this first prints the file name "o3d3xx.json" and then the data:

```
{'Applications': [{'Description': '',
                   'ImagerConfiguration': [{'AutoExposureMaxLongShortFactor': 50,
                                            'AutoExposureMinLongShortFactor': 2,


          (... lots and lots and lots of data ...)


             'StaticIPv4SubNetMask': '255.255.255.0',
             'UseDHCP': False}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked perfectly!!